# Get current shipping method in Woocommerce with jQuery

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, shipping-method

I spent my last few days to find or write a pure jQuery script to get the current shipping method from Woocommerce and find out if it is local pickup. I actually want to find it out before customer goes onto the cart or checkout page, as I have a side cart operating and you can select it over there or it selects automatically the first one available to that zone. So I the updated_checkout hook won't work I guess. With jQuery I can not read also the php sessions where it stored as far as I know, so is there any other ways?

Tried this, wait for the ajax to be done and then check but no luck for some reason...

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxStop( function($) {

jQuery( ".xoo-wsc-shipping-method" ).each(function( index ) {
if ($(this).val() === "local_pickup:22") {
alert("LOCAL PICKUP DETECTED");
} 
});

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it is working now :)

The working code:

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxStop( function($) {

jQuery( ".xoo-wsc-shipping-method" ).each(function( index ) {
if (jQuery(this).val() === "local_pickup:22") {
alert("LOCAL PICKUP DETECTED");
} 
});

});
```